# if row exists within foreach doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo, foreach

I am submitting html data array through ajax. My form look like:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="sel1">Select Class:</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="class_id" id="class_id">
        <?php
            $query=$con->query("SELECT * FROM class ORDER BY id ASC") or die($con->error);
            while($row=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['class_name']?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <br />
    <label>Add Section: </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="section_name" value="A">A</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="section_name" value="B">B</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="section_name" value="C">C</label>
    <br />
</form>
```

Array and input has been passed as following way to php

```
<script>
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var class_id = $("#class_id").val();
        var section_name = [];
        $("input[name='section_name']:checked").each(function(){
            section_name.push(this.value);
        });
        $.ajax({
                url: 'insert_section.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {class_id:class_id,section_name:section_name},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                }
            });
    }); 
</script>
```

I am trying to echo message in case of row exist or not. But it doesn't work. What is error in following code. Maybe foreach clause caused problem. Please help

```
if(isset($_POST["section_name"])){
foreach ($_POST["section_name"] AS $key => $item) {               
$query =$con->prepare("SELECT class_id, section_name FROM section WHERE class_id= ':class_id' && section_name ':section_name')");
$query->bindParam(':section_name',$_POST["section_name"][$key]);
$query->bindParam(':class_id', $_POST["class_id"]);
$query->execute();
$count = $query->fetchColumn();
    if ($count === 1)
    {
        echo "Section found";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Section is not found";
    }
}
}
```

My database looks like

[image]

Comment: Just as a general thing - you only need to prepare the statement once, not for every time in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Don't include quotes `'` in query. Also you can use directly `$item` varaible instead of `$_POST["section_name"][$key]` in loop. Change your code as below:

```
if(isset($_POST["section_name"])){
foreach ($_POST["section_name"] AS $key => $item) {               
$query =$con->prepare("SELECT class_id, section_name FROM section WHERE class_id= :class_id && section_name = :section_name)");
$query->bindParam(':section_name',$item);
$query->bindParam(':class_id', $_POST["class_id"]);
$query->execute();
$count = $query->fetchColumn();
    if ($count === 1)
    {
        echo "Section found";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Section is not found";
    }
}
}
```

As you have to count your result. Change your query as below:

```
$query =$con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(class_id) as total_ids FROM section WHERE class_id= ':class_id' && section_name ':section_name')");
```

Comment: Also `section_name :section_name` is wrong.

Comment: Yes just missed it. corrected @u_mulder

Comment: @B.Desai. Thanks for your concern. But it doesn't work. Still it echo section is not found, though data is in database. It seems problem is in my database or input form. Please see updated question.

Comment: check update @DipakOjha

Comment: @B.Desai. When I add array to checkbox, now it return null and insert statement also doesn't work. Before than, insert worked, only if row exist condition was not working. I am re-coding to find from where I am suffering, so I replied to your comment a bit later. Please see my ajax code once. I think problem start from there. Thanks for your continuous support.

Comment: ok I have just note that you done it using ajax. And in jquery you are creating array so array nit needed in html name

Comment: In alert what are your getting?

Comment: @B.Desai. it return 'Section is not found', though data is in database (it had to return 'Section Found', in case of data is in database)

Comment: check my updated answer